# Mysql GUI for Redhat 6 - Offline Installation with all dependencies needed

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, redhat

I am looking for a RPM for a MySQL GUI for Redhat 6. My Problem is, that I do not have an internet connection at the target system. For this reason I am looking for an installer or rpm where all dependencies are included.

I hope you can help me.

PhpMyAdmin would be super nice *-*.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Manually

I think the easy solution is to check the [phpMyAdmin requirements](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/require.html) (which are pretty minimal if you already have a working webserver, PHP, and MySQL installation), then just download the source and uncompress to your web root.

### Prepackaged kit

There are a number of prepackaged kits such as XAMPP that include all the requirements in one installer. If you already have an existing MySQL server, this will conflict with that so you'll want to back up your existing databases, migrate your databases to the new system, then remove the old MySQL server.

### RPM

This might require a bit of extra work simply to make sure you satisfy all the dependencies, but the phpMyAdmin RPM should work fine. You're able to install RPM files from the disk, although of course the usual method is to download them on-demand so many people aren't aware of this option. Note that phpMyAdmin is part of the EPEL repositories.

I'm assuming you already have MySQL running on the machine, so most of the more difficult dependencies should already be installed.

On your local Redhat system, download the RPM file for phpMyAdmin. Then use `rpm` to find the dependencies: `rpm -qpR phpmyadmin`. Compare to what's already installed on the target system and download any missing dependencies manually. This is the hard part, since you'll be doing a lot of the work by hand. Once you've got all the files you need, copy them to the target system where you can install them with `rpm -i <filename>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) It helped me!